# Required return keyword

Tags: scala, functional-programming, return, pattern-matching

So I am relatively new to Scala and working through Functional Programming in Scala and just ran across something new in one of the practice problems.  In hasSequences, I am required to place the return keyword in front of my return value or else nothing will return and the next line will execute.  Why is this required?

```
def hasSubsequence[A](list: List[A], subList: List[A]) : Boolean = {
    def matcher(l: List[A], sl: List[A]): List[A] = {
      if (sl.isEmpty) return Nil

      l match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case head :: tail if (head == sl.head) => head :: matcher(tail, sl.tail)
        case head :: tail => matcher(tail, sl)
        case _ => Nil
      }
    }
    if (matcher(list, subList) == subList) true else false
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's required because Scala treats the return value as either the last value in the function, or a value following the `return` keyword. Since your example isn't the last thing in the function, how would Scala know you wanted to return it? Imagine a situation where you use a function with side effects which also has a return value. If you call the function without assigning the result to anything, there would be no way to determine if you wanted to return that value or not without these restrictions.

You could modify your function like this:

```
def hasSubsequence[A](list: List[A], subList: List[A]) : Boolean = {
  def matcher(l: List[A], sl: List[A]): List[A] = {
    if (sl.isEmpty) Nil
    else l match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case head :: tail if (head == sl.head) => head :: matcher(tail, sl.tail)
      case head :: tail => matcher(tail, sl)
      case _ => Nil
    }
  }
  if (matcher(list, subList) == subList) true else false
}
```

to avoid the return. Since this makes the `match` part of the same `if` statement as the `return`, it all becomes part of the latest statement, and you no longer need to explicitly `return`.

Comment: @DaveM And this is typically how you'd write it in a functional language like Haskell that enforces purity. The style `if (empty) return Nil; something_else` is technically an imperative program, since it relies on a sequence of steps being executed in order. That doesn't make it *bad*; it's normal Scala idiom to write code that is "imperative locally" like this. But in languages that are stricter about defining a function by giving an expression for its result (rather than a "recipe" for producing a result), the "if with no else" style is impossible.

Comment: (Which means Haskell has no need of a `return` keyword, freeing it to confuse everybody by giving the name `return` to a function in the standard library that is almost, but not quite, entirely unlike the `return` keyword from other languages).